# How to compare the contents of two JSON files with TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, json, typescript

How can I compare the contents of two JSON files in Angular and achieve the following result:

Let's say that I have a ***default.json*** file that looks like this:

***default.json***

```
 {
  "name": "John"
  "age": 30,
  "car1": "Ford"
  "car2": "BMW"
  "car3": "Fiat"
 }
```

And another ***specific.json*** file that looks like this:

***specific.json***

```
 {
  "name": "Doe",
  "car1": "Tesla",
  "car4": "Mercedes"
 }
```

The ***default.json*** contains always all possible keys and the ***specific.json*** the keys, which should be overwritten and additional keys, which are not contained in the ***default.json*** *(in my example: "car4").*

**Now the following should be checked by the comparison:**

If a specific key *(in my example "name" and "car1")* has a different value in the ***specific.json*** than in the ***default.json*** for the same keys, then these values ​​should be overwritten and used. Otherwise always the default values ​​from the ***default.json*** and the additional values ​​from the ***specific.json*** of course *(in my example "car4")*.

At the end both files should be used, so the specific.json serves only as an update or extension of the default.json. I need this functionality in an Angular app, where I have to compare two JSON files and then use the [ngx-translate](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core) library to provide specific translations based on specific business cases of the application. Check also my question about this topic please if you want: [Translations based on specific keys in custom JSON files and business cases with ngx-translate (Angular 7)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54889527/translations-based-on-specific-keys-in-custom-json-files-and-business-cases-with)

I hope I could explain it well :)

Comment: How is this related to angular?

Comment: `Object.assign(parsedDatafromDefault, parsedDataFromSpecific)`?

Comment: `const newObj = { ...defaultObj, ...specificObj };`

Comment: @tic Because I need it in an Angular app, where I have to compare two JSON files and then use the ngx-translate library to provide specific translations based on specific business cases of the application.

Comment: @adiga With this, the equal keys will be overwritten but what about the additional keys that are not in the default.json but in the specific.json?

Comment: Then the `specific` property will be taken: [Object.assign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get a list of the differences between two JavaScript object graphs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/264430/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-the-differences-between-two-javascript-object-graphs)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I merge properties of two JavaScript objects dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171251/how-can-i-merge-properties-of-two-javascript-objects-dynamically)

Comment: @tic I did not know that the spread operator overrides the same keys. I'll try that.

Comment: @RomanticElectron That will never enter the body of the if, since the condition will always be false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use es6 spread operator to merge (And override) objects

```
const defaultObj = {
  name: 'John',
  age: 30,
  car1: 'Ford',
  car2: 'BMW',
  car3: 'Fiat'
};

const specificObj = {
  name: 'Doe',
  car1: 'Tesla',
  car4: 'Mercedes'
}

console.log({ ...defaultObj, ...specificObj });
```

Comment: I just tried it and it also seems to work with my ngx-translate solution. I will try to continue working with this solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This is not related with Angular, but with JS.

Below example how to do it with objects.

```js
let def = {
  "name": "John",
  "age": 30,
  "car1": "Ford",
  "car2": "BMW",
  "car3": "Fiat"
};

let specific = {
  "name": "Doe",
  "car1": "Tesla",
  "car4": "Mercedes"
}

function compose(def, spec) {
  return Object.assign(def, spec);
}

console.log(compose(def, specific));
```

Output:

```
/*
{ 
  name: 'Doe',
  age: 30,
  car1: 'Tesla',
  car2: 'BMW',
  car3: 'Fiat',
  car4: 'Mercedes' 
}
*/
```